# In Python, how can I add another module to an already existing variable that contains one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible use a variable as a container for a Python module, and then adding another one to the same variable?

So for example, if I would have a Python file called *general_config.py* containing a general config of some kind:

```
class GeneralConfig:
    attribute1 = "Some attribute"
    attribute2 = "Some other attribute"
```

And if I would import this Python module as a variable containing a general config, I would do:

```
import general_config.py as Config
```

Then I can access its attributes by doing:

```
generalParameter = Config.GeneralConfig.attribute1
```

But what if I want to add some specific parameters to my config (say from *specific_config.py*), while keeping the general one as part of the entire config? So it would do something like that:

```
if someSpecificCondition:
    Config += import specific_config.py
else:
    Config += import other_config.py
```

While keeping the Config in the original scope? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any other classes in `general_config.py`? If not, what purpose does `GeneralConfig` serve that the module `general_config` does not?

Comment: Yes there are. The purpose is to start the program using some general parameters which will be used to determine what kind of specific config I need for the rest of the program. So that's why I had to split the configuration parameters into two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your general config to *inherit* your other configs for whatever reason, you could do something like this. But Tom's answer makes more sense, since there's no runtime class creation.

```py
class BaseConfig:
    att = "hello world"


def inherit_configs(some_condition):
    if some_condition:
        from config1 import Config1

        class Config(BaseConfig, Config1):
            pass

        return Config
    else:
        from config2 import Config2

        class Config(BaseConfig, Config2):
            pass

        return Config


config = inherit_configs(some_condition)()
```